# Error while running Sqoop job from Hue

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to create a Sqoop Job from Hue; Under "Job Designer" I created a new job inputting teh command to create a sqoop job as below.

```
sqoop job --create TestHiveImport -- import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ipaddress>:port/<database_name> --username <username> --password <password> --table TEST_SQOOP --hive-import --hive-table trade.test_sqoop --hive-drop-import-delims --incremental lastmodified --check-column LAST_MODIFIED --last-value "1970-01-01 00:01:01.0" -m 1
```

After I submitted the job; I am getting below error. Please help, am totally stuck.

```
2014-12-19 09:19:40,928  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2014-12-19 09:19:40,928  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2014-12-19 09:19:40,928  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2014-12-19 09:19:40,950  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] end executor for wf action 0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W with wf job 0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W
2014-12-19 09:19:41,018  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] Start action [0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2014-12-19 09:19:41,179  WARN SqoopActionExecutor:542 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] credentials is null for the action
2014-12-19 09:19:41,495  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] Trying to get job [job_1415818455534_0502], attempt [1]
2014-12-19 09:19:41,507  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] checking action, external ID [job_1415818455534_0502] status [RUNNING]
2014-12-19 09:19:41,508  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] [***0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop***]Action status=RUNNING
2014-12-19 09:19:41,509  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] [***0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop***]Action updated in DB!
2014-12-19 09:19:52,651  INFO CallbackServlet:539 - USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] callback for action [0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop]
2014-12-19 09:19:52,714  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] Trying to get job [job_1415818455534_0502], attempt [1]
2014-12-19 09:19:52,714  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] Trying to get job [job_1415818455534_0502], attempt [1]
2014-12-19 09:19:52,778  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] action completed, external ID [null]
2014-12-19 09:19:52,784  WARN SqoopActionExecutor:542 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
2014-12-19 09:19:52,808  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] end executor for wf action 0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W with wf job 0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W
2014-12-19 09:19:52,832  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@TestSqoop] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2014-12-19 09:19:52,881  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@kill] Start action [0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@kill] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2014-12-19 09:19:52,882  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@kill] [***0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@kill***]Action status=DONE
2014-12-19 09:19:52,882  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@kill] [***0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@kill***]Action updated in DB!
2014-12-19 09:19:52,904  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W@kill] end executor for wf action 0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W with wf job 0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W
2014-12-19 09:19:52,973  WARN CoordActionUpdateXCommand:542 - USER[scbengr2] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[TestSqoop] JOB[0000002-141008154216525-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[-] E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100
```

Comment: it looks like a permission issue to me. If you are sure that your sqoop command works in the bash. Then you might want to check if you user account `scbengr2` have the correct privileges on the write folder. Also, make sure you have the connector and hive-conf.xml file accessible to your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Hue currently has [3 ways](http://ingest.tips/2014/10/21/sqoop-1-or-sqoop-2/) of launching Sqoop:

1. Job Designer
2. Sqoop app
3. Oozie app

The Job Designer internally uses Oozie, hence the output you see above.

I see a few things wrong with the command you've provided above:

1. The command is creating a job, not running one.
2. The command includes `sqoop`, which will not work appropriately.
3. Creating a job through oozie requires an [external metastore](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_metastore_literal) and for the job to somehow have this configuration.

Solution:

1. Instead of using the metastore, try just running the sqoop command: `import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ipaddress>:port/<database_name> --username <username> --password <password> --table TEST_SQOOP --hive-import --hive-table trade.test_sqoop --hive-drop-import-delims --incremental lastmodified --check-column LAST_MODIFIED --last-value "1970-01-01 00:01:01.0" -m 1`.
2. Instead of adding `sqoop` before the command, try removing it: `job --create TestHiveImport -- import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ipaddress>:port/<database_name> --username <username> --password <password> --table TEST_SQOOP --hive-import --hive-table trade.test_sqoop --hive-drop-import-delims --incremental lastmodified --check-column LAST_MODIFIED --last-value "1970-01-01 00:01:01.0" -m 1`.
3. You can add the Sqoop metastore information to `sqoop-site.xml`. Check with the [mailing lists](http://sqoop.apache.org/mail-lists.html) for help with that.